# How do I add more than one inheritance relationship in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy, polymorphism

So, I have a users table, and employees table, and a tenants table.

I'm using joined table inheritance.

```
class User(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'usr_users'

    usr_user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    usr_first_name = Column(Unicode(50))
    usr_last_name = Column(Unicode(50))

    tenant = relationship("Tenant", uselist=False, backref="User")

    usr_type = Column(String(24))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'user',
        'polymorphic_on': usr_type
    }

class Tenant(User):
    """
    Application's user model.
    """
    __tablename__ = 'ten_tenants'

    ten_tenant_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('usr_users.usr_user_id'), primary_key=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'tenant'
    }


class Employee(User):
    __tablename__ = 'emp_employees'

    emp_employee_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('usr_users.usr_user_id'), primary_key=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'employee'
    }
```

I've got everything working when a user becomes an employee.

```
    user = Employee()
    session.add(user)
```

An entry in the user table, and a value in the "type" column of "employee".

But what if I have a user that is both a employee and a tenant?

What syntax do I use to pull the user, and then add a Tenant relationship so that the resulting user has both a employee relationship and a tenant relationship?